# Swift generic func cannot convert value of type to expected argument type

Tags: swift, generic-programming, corestore

I try to create generic func

```
func importArray<T: ImportableUniqueObject>(from exercisesDict: [[String: Any]], transaction: BaseDataTransaction) -> [T] {

    if let managedObject = try? transaction.fetchOne(From<T>()){

        transaction.delete(managedObject)
    }

    let managedObjects = try! transaction.importUniqueObjects(
        Into<T>(),
        sourceArray: jsonObjects)


    return managedObjects

    }
```

So first part works good:

```
if let managedObject = try? transaction.fetchOne(From<T>()){
```

,but second does not work:

```
let managedObjects = try! transaction.importUniqueObjects(
        Into<T>(),
        sourceArray: jsonObjects)
```

Compiler says

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Into<T>' to expected argument type 'Into<_>'
```

This is how func is constructed:

```
public func importUniqueObjects<D: ImportableUniqueObject, S: Sequence>(
        _ into: Into<D>,
        sourceArray: S,
        preProcess: @escaping (_ mapping: [D.UniqueIDType: D.ImportSource]) throws -> [D.UniqueIDType: D.ImportSource] = { $0 }) throws -> [D] where S.Iterator.Element == D.ImportSource {
```

Comment: Is the error caused by the closure argument `preProcess` that is not given in the call?

Comment: looks like `Into<T>()` throws this

Comment: somehow we need to let compiler now that T type implements ImportableUniqueObject, so I declared it as ImportableUniqueObject but looks like this is not enough

Comment: for example if I want to do this `let settings = try transaction.importUniqueObject(
                Into<UserSettingsEntity>(),` by passing not generic but exact type I want and `UserSettingsEntity` does not contain ImportableUniqueObject implemented functions I see this Cannot convert value of type as well.

Comment: such function works good:

 `func mergedExercises<T: ExerciseEntity>(from jsonObjects: [[String: Any]], transaction: BaseDataTransaction) -> [T] {` when I declared T with needed class type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a compiler bug. Had the same issue when Xcode 10 came out.
Adapt your method to the following:

```
func importArray<T: ImportableUniqueObject>(from exercisesDict: [[String: Any]], transaction: BaseDataTransaction) -> [T] where T.ImportSource == [String: Any] {
    let managedObjects = try? transaction.importUniqueObjects(Into<T>(), sourceArray: jsonObjects)
}
```

Though I recommend do not do force-try when importing.

Also see: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8945

Comment: thanks for the answer again!!!!)

now when I try to call this function `importArray(from: exercisesDict, transaction: transaction)` 

I get this error `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`

Comment: You need to specify your T somewhere. Call it like let importedArray: YourTypeT = importArray(from....

Comment: hm, now it works but I can operate with managedObject as I don't know what exactly T is ) maybe you know some workout around. So I need somehow modify property id of this `let managedObject = try? transaction.fetchOne(From<T>() `

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more in detail? I don't understand what you want to achieve in your comment.

Comment: Sure I've added a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57494689/swift-generic-functions-issues-decrease-duplicating-code, thanks for help!! Let me know if you need more details, really want to get rid of duplication))