# Swift generic functions issues. Decrease duplicating code

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I want to understand how can decrease amount of duplicated code. I have two almost the same functions. The differences are next:

firs function returns array of `[ExerciseEntity]`  and second function returns array of `[WorkoutEntity]`

```
func replaceExercisesIdentifiers(from jsonObjects: [[String: Any]], transaction: BaseDataTransaction) -> [ExerciseEntity] {

        for jsonObject in jsonObjects {
            if let mobileLocalId = jsonObject["mobileLocalId"] as? String {
                if mobileLocalId.contains("<x-coredata://") {
                    if let managedObject = try? transaction.fetchOne(From<ExerciseEntity>()
                        .where(
                            format: "%K == %@",
                            #keyPath(BaseMO.id),
                            mobileLocalId)
                        ) {
                        let editObject = transaction.edit(managedObject)
                        if let identifier = jsonObject["id"] as? String {
                            editObject?.id = identifier
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        let managedObjects = try! transaction.importUniqueObjects(
            Into<ExerciseEntity>(),
            sourceArray: jsonObjects)

        return managedObjects
    }

    func replaceWorkoutsIdentifiers(from jsonObjects: [[String: Any]], transaction: BaseDataTransaction) -> [WorkoutEntity] {

        for jsonObject in jsonObjects {
            if let mobileLocalId = jsonObject["mobileLocalId"] as? String {
                if mobileLocalId.contains("<x-coredata://") {
                    if let managedObject = try? transaction.fetchOne(From<WorkoutEntity>()
                        .where(
                            format: "%K == %@",
                            #keyPath(BaseMO.id),
                            mobileLocalId)
                        ) {
                        let editObject = transaction.edit(managedObject)
                        if let identifier = jsonObject["id"] as? String {
                            editObject?.id = identifier
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        let managedObjects = try! transaction.importUniqueObjects(
            Into<WorkoutEntity>(),
            sourceArray: jsonObjects)

        return managedObjects
    }
```

This is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55976440/swift-generic-func-cannot-convert-value-of-type-to-expected-argument-type/56006515?noredirect=1#comment101458665_56006515) related to how to use generic function I asked before.

I implemented this in my code but:

```
func importArray<T: ImportableUniqueObject>(from exercisesDict: [[String: Any]], transaction: BaseDataTransaction) -> [T] where T.ImportSource == [String: Any] {
    let managedObjects = try? transaction.importUniqueObjects(Into<T>(), sourceArray: jsonObjects)
}
```

But here is few things, with T type

First - I can't add this code: `editObject?.id = identifier`

as there is no `id` in `T type`.

Second when I debug these generic functions debugger every time crashes:

```
Message from debugger: The LLDB RPC server has crashed. The crash log is located in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports and has a prefix 'lldb-rpc-server'. Please file a bug and attach the most recent crash log.
```

If interesting here is a [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WSL062pRUQacZusIpYVKxXjgXbUQwjWe) with log. I have not submitted it yet.

For sure I can add a lot of prints to track behavior, though it's a but annoying) But main task is to get rid of duplication.

Comment: What about adding a protocol with `id` as a property and then defining the function as `func replaceIdentifiers<T: NSManagedObject, MyProtocol>(from jsonObjects: [[String: Any]], transaction: BaseDataTransaction) -> [T]`?

Comment: You could just have your func importArray<T: BaseMO> to be more explicit about the conformance of T, as all your BaseMO will have "id".

Comment: @MartinM I think about it, but the problem is that the `BaseMO` is not `ImportableUniqueObject` itself. It just includes some properties of a parent object, but I never import `BaseMO` thought my other entities subclassed from it.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense for you in that case to have BaseMO adopt ImportableUniqueObject? As that is what you apparently want to achieve here. It doesnt mean you have to import objects of that specific type. Hint: abstract coredata entity when you setup your schema.

Comment: @MartinM yea probably a solution thanks! will try and reply

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I have not tested):

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var id: Int { get set }
}

struct ExerciseEntity {
    var id: Int
}    

struct WorkoutEntity {
    var id: Int
} 

func replaceWorkoutsIdentifiers<T: MyProtocol>(from jsonObjects: [[String: Any]], transaction: BaseDataTransaction) -> [T] {

    for jsonObject in jsonObjects {
        if let mobileLocalId = jsonObject["mobileLocalId"] as? String {
            if mobileLocalId.contains("<x-coredata://") {
                if let managedObject = try? transaction.fetchOne(From<T>()
                    .where(
                        format: "%K == %@",
                        #keyPath(BaseMO.id),
                        mobileLocalId)
                    ) {
                    let editObject = transaction.edit(managedObject)
                    if let identifier = jsonObject["id"] as? String {
                        editObject?.id = identifier
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    let managedObjects = try! transaction.importUniqueObjects(
        Into<T>(),
        sourceArray: jsonObjects)

    return managedObjects as! T
}
```

Using:

```
let array: [ExerciseEntity] = replaceWorkoutsIdentifiers(from jsonObjects: ..., transaction: ...)
```

Comment: you've meant `struct ExerciseEntity : MyProtocol` right? ok it's an idea but I use `CoreStore` and I need to be able to conform my `NSManagedObject` objects this protocol ImportableUniqueObject, or you mean I can combine it?

Comment: You may only be able to conform it to NSManagedObject if in the protocol there is the id, I do not know your project. But you can conform an object of as many protocols as you want

Comment: the problem is that the transaction.fetchOne(From<T>() will not allow to do it as it should conform to DynamicObject protocol and this is CoreStore protocol which does not know about BaseMO.id

thanks for help